# When setting up Solaris, how do you determine what your domain name is?

Tags: solaris, domain-name

I'm at this step in the set-up process :

[image]

Is this just my computer's IP address?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's your actual domain name. You can leave that screen blank if you want,
which should be fine if you're getting your system's actual domain name from a
dhcp server.

btw, on the screenshot you provided, you appear to have hit a function key
rather than [escape] and a number. Backspace is friendly here.

Finally ... how about trying a newer release than Solaris 10? You can get Solaris 11 and updates from http://www.oracle.com, which would provide you with a much
nicer installation experience and greatly improved operation over Solaris 10.